# Git Revert "revert is not possible because you have unmerged files"

Tags: git, revert

I did a simple example to text some GIT functions. Just one  text file in the repository:

```
1
```

added and commited the change

then changed the txt. file to:

```
1
2
```

added and commited the change

Git log gives the following result:

```
commit 00e59212a6...
..
second commit

commit 7c319d587....
..
first commit
```

at that point I want to go back to the first commit (but I dont want to use "reset --hard". I tried:

```
git revert 7c319d587
```

but i got the following error message:

```
revert is not possible because you have unmerged files
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and the use "git add/rm
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit
```

I am new to GIT - before I used SVN, there you can handle such things very simple so I am wondering if this simple things need a few steps in GIT?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: It sounds like something else added a file (e.g. editor backup files). Try `git status` to get a view of what git thinks is going on.

Comment: git status --> On branch master; you are currently reverting commit 7c319d587. (fix conflicts and run "git revert --continue") (use git revert --abort to cancel the revert operation); unmerged paths: (use"git reset Heat <file>.." to unstage); delted by them: test.txt; no changes added to commit(use "git add" and or "git commit -a)

Answer (score 4):

Well, I have tried what You think You did, by doing exactly what You wrote

```
cd /tmp
mkdir so35588521
cd so35588521
git init
# Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/so35588521/.git/
touch 1
echo "1" > 1
git add .
git commit -m "first"
# [master (root-commit) 173f431] first
#  1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
# create mode 100644 1
touch 2
touch 3
git add .
git commit -m "second"
# [master a9fdcc9] second
#  2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
#  create mode 100644 2
#  create mode 100644 3
git log
# commit a9fdcc9338c9b3de25c211580a35ab63d1d57c2e
# Author: Me and my email
# Date:   Tue Feb 23 22:46:50 2016 +0100
git revert a9fd
# [master dd5a86e] Revert "second"
# 2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
# delete mode 100644 2
# delete mode 100644 3
```

as You can see - all went well. Thus, I thought, *AHA! She/he must have done something else, and neglected to mention it on SO. Oh well, I'll figure out what she/he did using my crystal ball anyway. What's the point of it laying around useless.*

So, merge, git said. Then, let's make a branch and try to merge it with our master branch.

```
git checkout -b a_branch
# Switched to a new branch 'a_branch'
echo "2" > 1
git status
# On branch a_branch ...
git add .
git commit -m "third"
# [a_branch 96d3a7a] third
#  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
git checkout master
# Switched to branch 'master'
echo "3" > 1
git add .
git commit -m "fourth"
# [master 7f72eec] fourth
#  1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
#### Now we have first commit, and second, and revert second, and two commits: third on **a_branch** branch and fourth on **master**. 
git merge a_branch
# Auto-merging 1
# CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in 1
# Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
# *Oh DANG* whyy? Git stop, don't do that it hurts, revert!
git revert last_commit_id_from_git_log
# error: revert is not possible because you have unmerged files.
# hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
# hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
# fatal: revert failed
# *Git nope!*
```

Now, that was just me guessing, and bringing a little bit of humor to SO, I hope. If this is NOT what You did, could You please tell us exact steps You did? Since I can't replicate error You are having, and thus I feel unfulfilled not being able to hellp.

EDIT:

Since OP insists that definitely did not make a branch...

```
rm *
rm -rf .git
git init
echo -e "line one\n" > 1
git add .
git ci -m "first"
echo -e "line two\n" >> 1
git ci -a -m "second"
git log
# commit 23d710610d98c1046844870557208f335e76a933
# Author: ME <me@home>
# Date:   Tue Feb 23 23:31:28 2016 +0100
#
#     second
# 
# commit 22873fb5fbf06d80a1779fe6740060c660d68714
# Author: ME <me@home>
# Date:   Tue Feb 23 23:30:47 2016 +0100
#
#    first

git revert "first"
# fatal: bad revision 'first'  # but OK i assume You used id, so,
git revert 22873fb5fbf06d80
# error: could not revert 22873fb... first
# hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
# hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
# hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

Ahaaa, now i got it! And that...is bizzaare.

Ok, I checked and actually You are right, on my `git --version` 2.6.3 I could replicate this behavior. Actually, I think You went into quite corner case here. What happened is, that after Your second commit, git stored changes You made to file `test.txt` and kept those changes. Now You told him(it?) to `git revert first_commit_id` which actually created file test.txt. I can't tell for sure but this seems like a small bug for me.

**However!** If You, in second commit - add file, for example `test2.txt` (so You would have two files versioned in git repository), then `revert` works.

Comment: :) thank you: 1) created a txt file /added/ committed 2) added a second line to that file / saved / added / commited 3) git revert "first commit" --> got error: is not possible because you have unmerged files 4) I never changed or created a new branch 5) git status --> On branch master; you are currently reverting commit 7c319d587. (fix conflicts and run "git revert --continue") (use git revert --abort to cancel the revert operation); unmerged paths: (use"git reset Heat <file>.." to unstage); delted by them: test.txt; no changes added to commit(use "git add" and or "git commit -a)

Comment: Let me just add that to answer, so You could confirm You did exactly that. I still cannot replicate what You did.

Comment: So, since I can replicate it, and consider this minor bug, I'll issue a bug request for git maintainers (after checking bleeding edge git) unless You want to :)